# запускаю сервер и вылетают ошибки

Tags: node.js, сервер

pr@1.0.0 start

> node app.js

node:events:368
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1334:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1382:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1469:7)
at Function.listen (/Users/aleksandra/Моргунова Dropbox/Александра Моргунова/Mac/Documents/pr/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
at start (/Users/aleksandra/Моргунова Dropbox/Александра Моргунова/Mac/Documents/pr/app.js:11:9)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1361:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -48,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 5000
}

Comment: Ошибка «address already in use» говорит о том, что уже запущен какой-то другой сервер

Comment: а подскажите пожалуйста как выключить другой сервер?